# Update Named Ranges values

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any code to update values in named ranges? I would like to make it whenever I run my code.

I know that you can loop through Named ranges but how I can update/refresh them?

```
Sub NamedRange_Loop()

Dim nm As Name

'Loop through each named range in workbook
  For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    Debug.Print nm.Name, nm.RefersTo
  Next nm

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by update/ refresh? Are you talking about `Calculate`?

Comment: I have data that is connected to our File Management system M-Files. It uses named ranges to connect values from M-Files metadata to Excel. The problem is I need these values on Workbook_Open. It takes like 10 seconds to load these values from Named ranges to cells on Worksheet when I open Excel workbook. I would like to perform Named Ranges loading/updating/refreshing or whatever the correct name is by VBA code.